# Duplicate views or add parameters

Tags: django, web, view

I want to build a django application where the users are workers in a callcenter. When they talk to a client they have a specific task, but at some point they optionally might need to update the client's contact data.

The point is that there already is a view for updating the contact data. The only thing that would need to change (at the moment) is the URL you get send to after submit/cancel. So I am wondering whether I should reuse that view. I can think of roughly three options:

- Reuse the view and pass the return URL as parameter
- Create a new view that reuses parts of the existing view (e.g. template)
- Create a completely new view

What would you recommend and why?

Comment: Is there anything missing in the current view? Why not to use existing endpoint to update that data?

Answer (score 0):

Option number one seems to be fine, because it reuses a lot of code. But I think it'd be a bit better to not to send such URL by parameter (an advantage that I can see: user wouldn't know the redirect URL if POST is failed).

If there are just 2 options where the user is redirected, you could consider sending boolean parameter, sth like `url?during_call=1`. And then in your view you could add a small ifology:

```
def view(request):
    # your logic here
    during_call = request.POST.get('during_call', False)
    redirect_url = 'url1' if during_call else 'url2'
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```